# Чистая архетектура - как правильно делать роутинг?

Tags: java, android, mvp

Пишу одноактивное приложение и роутинг тут оказался слишком сложным и от этого активити начало плодить методы перехода между экранами ведь у каждого свой какойто переход, как правильно осуществлять переход в таком случае, у меня просто методы по разные навигации и фрагмент юзает методы активити то это крайне не удобно. Как правильно в рамках mvp + чистая архитектура делать переходы по навигации между фрагментами

Comment: перезадайте, пожалуйста, вопрос, он абсолютно непонятен да еще и с ошибкам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Маловероятно, что у вас есть N переходов с одной активити. Скорее всего в главном активити вы показывает фрагмент № 1. По клику на различные области/кнопки вы должны выполняете переходы с текущего фрагмента на другой, оставаясь в рамках этого же активити. Само активити занимается чем-то общим для всех фрагментов, например, организация меню. В таком случае, не вижу никаких проблем. Для замены фрагмента, в активити у вас реализован примерно такой метод:

```
fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, stackEnable: Boolean) {
    val tr = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    tr.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_animation_enter, R.anim.right_animation_leave)
    tr.replace(R.id.mainContainer, fragment, fragment.tag)
    if (stackEnable)
        tr.addToBackStack(null)
    tr.commit()
}
```

который вы дергаете из своих фрагментов по callback-у.